# ¿Por qué el comando For Each no devuelve los valores correctos en Genexus 18?

Tags: sql-server, date, genexus, foreach, count

Estoy trabajando con Genexus 18 y tengo 2 casos:

**Caso 1:**
Tengo la siguiente subrutina que tiene un comando For Each desde un WebPanel

```
//En Genexus (devuelve 1218)
sub 'Count IDs'
    &totIds = 0
    for each miTransaccion 
        Where id_proceso = 230404416
        Where YEAR(fec_venc.ToDate()) = 2023
        Where MONTH(fec_venc.ToDate()) = 7
        &totIds += 1 
    endfor  
endsub
```

En donde:

&totIds Numeric(10)

fec_venc DateTime

Lo que deseo es sencillamente mostrar en un TextBlock el total de registros (almacenado en la variable &totIds) con las condiciones mencionadas (que sea del año 2023, del mes 7 (julio) y con el ID 230404416.

Al mandar a llamar a 'Count IDs' me devuelve 1218 registros, pero al pasarlo a SQL Server me devuelve 1224

```
//Desde SQL Server (devuelve 1224)
select count(fec_venc) from miTransaccion
where id_proceso = 230404416
and year(fec_venc) = 2023
and month(fec_venc) = 7
```

Cabe mencionar que si únicamente pongo el filtro where de id_proceso

```
where id_proceso = 230404416
```

sí me devuelve los resultados correctos, al parecer hay un problema con la fecha ya que es allí cuando los totales ya no están bien.

**Caso 2:**

Tengo un reporte que leo directamente con un For Each, sin ningúna condición Where porque los valores que están en esa tabla ya fueron filtrados por otro proceso, es decir, deseo mostrar todos los valores tal cuál están en la tabla.

Aproximadamente son 50 campos y el reporte devuelve exactamente la misma información, el problema está en que en los campos de fecha (DateTime) sí devuelve bien la fecha, pero por alguna razón que no entiendo en la parte de la hora cambia (para todas las columnas/campos que son fecha (DateTime).

[image: Reporte GX VS SQL]

**¿Por qué sucede esto, de qué me estoy perdiendo?**

Notas (caso 1):

Tengo más ejemplos (varios id_procesos) y en todos muestra la cantidad correcta **sólo si lo filtro por id_proceso, pero al incluir la fecha (fec_venc) ya no me muestra el total correcto**.

Ya lo intenté de otras muchas formas (conviertiendo el campo de mi transacción directamente a Date), pasando a variables los valores de los campos, pasando el For Each a un Procedimiento y mandándolo a llamar desde mi Web Panel, etc., pero nada me funciona.

Ya le di a 'Build All/Re-Build All', pero no cambia nada

En vez de 2023 y 7 (año y mes) voy a poner el año y mes actual, de esta forma (por eso no pongo fijo el TextBlock):

```
and year(fec_venc) = YEAR(NOW())
and month(fec_venc) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. La plataforma está diseñada para que haya una pregunta por publicación (que se llama pregunta, por eso). Si tienes dos _casos_, lo mejor es que hagas dos publicaciones, de otra manera me temo que esta termine cerrada por el mismo motivo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pareceria que es un tema con el valor que tienes en la propiedad DateTime Storage TimeZone (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?17218,DateTime+storage+timezone+property)

Si tiene un valor diferente a "undefined" entonces considera la parte de hora de los DateTime para saber el dia.
Por lo cual intuyo que lo que pasa es que los registros del 1ro y/o 31 de Julio (mes 7) te están quedando fuera del rango.

Además en ese caso (hay un TimeZone establecido), las funciones que estás usando no se optimizan (no van en la sentencia SQL) por lo cual la sentencias que ejecutas directo contra el SQL es diferente a lo que hace el programa GeneXus en el for each. Más sobre eso: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22019,TimeZone+Support+-+General+Considerations

Comment: ese era mi problema, cambié la propiedad DateTime storage timezone a "Application Server" (lo tenía inicialmente en GMT/UTC) y funcionó perfectamente, ¡gracias!